# JS,CSS,jQuery DIV 3D effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for one specific effect but I'm not sure what's it called or how should I search for it.

Basically, I'm after a 3D effect.
I have a DIV element, I'd like it to behave like it's placed on a ball (which is located below the center of it).

So when you mouse over the edges that edge will zoom out/in.

Has anyone seen anything like it? Is this achievable at all?

Edit:
Behaviour [in this example best describes what I was after](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/text3d.html) but with DIVs not text.
I think I'll be able to adjust this example for my needs.

Sorry if my description was too general, I wasn't sure how to describe what I needed.

Comment: you mean like a cloud and when you pass the mouse over the element zooms ?

Comment: Can you add a better description please? Anyway take a look to https://github.com/hakimel/zoom.js maybe it will help you to start ;)

Comment: ower reloaded - thanx for your time. I edited the original question and actually found almost what I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS Transition for this.
with css transition you can animate divs or objects.

Look at this great tutorial

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions

an example:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Uw56J/)

```
<body>
    <p>The box below combines transitions for: width, height, background-color, transform. Hover over the box to see these properties animated.</p>
    <div class="box"></div>
</body>

.box {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    -moz-transition:width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, -moz-transform 2s;
    -webkit-transition:width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
    -o-transition:width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, -o-transform 2s;
    transition:width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
}
.box:hover {
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

Hope it is what you mean.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. This isn't really what I was after although it's a really cool effect. I'm trying to achieve depth effect somehow. Thanx again!

Comment: glad i helped a bit. if my answer was helpful you can accept it. and if you need more info i could provide that too.

Comment: Your answer is not what I wanted but somehow it lead me to http://cubiq.org/dropbox/text3d.html which is a variation of what I need. Thanx.